# What are sites where Substrate users look for Q&A? Can we highlight this StackExchange Beta there?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

One place I can think of is substrate.dev. We could e.g. ask the maintainers to add a top bar there, highlighting that there is currently an ongoing StackExchange Beta and that users should post their questions here (+ look for existing answers).

What are other sites where we should make people aware of this Beta?

Answer (score 2):

The owners of substrate.io have been notified to help add a banner to the site.

Great suggestion.

Comment: @JNat, you seem to have some comments about how you want the site to be advertised. Why don't you share that stuff publicly or talk to us in our Meta channel?

Answer (score 2):

It would be resourceful to see the pop-up window shown on https://substrate.io/ to be shown on all pages of https://docs.substrate.io/ as well. As the docs are where most of the devs go to when trying to learn Substrate. That way, new learners of Substrate know where to ask their questions.

Answer (score 2):

For ink! there is [a monthly digest](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/MONTHLY_UPDATE.md#stackexchange-beta) on things that happened.

I just added a section on this Beta there. Is anyone aware of more regular digests like this in the Substrate ecosystem?

Comment: Nice idea. Love the digest btw.

Answer (score 0):

We probably get a fair few questions on our you tube videos (spread thinly over a lot of videos). A hint there might be good if we can.